# How to read Daisy format book?

Tags: file-format, ebook

I have downloaded an **ebook** which as they had mention, is in **daisy** format. It is a zip file containing a number of files with **strange extensions**. *How do I read it?*

Comment: If you don't like Amis there are some alternatives https://alternativeto.net/software/amis/
Also, you will find that some eBook readers available in app stores offer Daisy support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AMIS (Adaptive Multimedia Information System)](http://www.daisy.org/amis/download) to read Daisy ebooks on a PC